# Canadian Expedia refund possibility for missed hotel

Tags: canada, hotels, refunds, expedia

I booked a hotel with Expedia for the day before I was supposed to be in town. When I arrived, obviously there was no reservation under my name, and I had to book a new room with the hotel itself. Is there any possibility of actually getting a refund or partial credit with Expedia Canada for the night I missed? The hotel had the restriction of no refunds.

Comment: I had a friend travelling in a group of 3. They turned up exactly 1 year before their flight date. Oops.

Comment: I can't see any reason to expect a refund from Expedia or from the hotel. FWIW - if you fail to take a flight and lose the fare, they are obliged to refund the taxes paid. You may have to yell at them rather loudly to convince them to remember their legal obligation.

Comment: I don't think Expedia would refund you for a mistake *you* made.

Answer (score 7):

Likely No.

You made the mistake, therefore the burden of responsibility and expense is yours.  Expedia paid your money to the hotel, the hotel held the room empty for you, so your payment is forfeit.

The only one who could perhaps offer a refund would be the hotel itself, but hotels usually stick to their guns on this no show issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've made this mistake in the past as well, especially when city-hopping in Argentina.  Essentially, no, it's your mistake, it's embarrassing, but it happens.

From Expedia's point of view: You've booked, and paid, and nothing went wrong with their service. Why should they refund?

From hotel's point of view: You booked, didn't show. They have no reason to refund either, and it'll be in their policy too.

One hostel I was at I'd booked the wrong night, and they kindly just moved the booking in the computer when I arrived and we worked out what'd happened, but that was totally out of the employee's kindness - there's no obligation on them to do it whatsoever.

If it helps, don't feel bad, [USA Today lists this action as one of the top 10 hotel booking mistakes travellers make](http://www.usatoday.com/story/travel/hotels/2014/08/14/hotel-booking-tips/14006883/), including the author.

Answer (score 0):

I took a chance and called Expedia anyway. The agent called the hotel while having me on the phone, and luckily I was able to receive most of my first night's fees back less $3. Definitely a much more favourable conclusion than what I expected.